# How to use ng-click with ngGrid

Tags: javascript, frontend, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-click

I use ngGrid for the real time data. It works without any problem and displays all the data in a meaningful way. Now, I want to have a 2nd table (or nggrid), which will be opened, when I click one of the rows in the current ngGrid. I think I need to ng-click. But, it did not work. Can you please tell me, how I can solve it?

**.html file**

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
    <h1>table1</h1>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

**.js file**

```
app.controller('controller1', function ($scope){

$scope.data = [];
$scope.loadById = function(row){
  window.console && console.log(row.entity);
  $window.location.href = 'newPage/?id=' + row.entity.id;
}

/* rest of the code, not related to this part */

$scope.gridOptions = {
data: 'data',
columnDefs: [{
   field: 'id', DisplayName: 'id',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="loadById(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'

        }]
    };`
```

Comment: Here you are: [http://plnkr.co/edit/SpdBn1?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/SpdBn1?p=info). Hope this help.

Comment: can you please. post the code here?

Comment: Code don't works here. I don't know why. Sorry.